# For Swift language, what is the difference in initializing structs versus initializing classes? (I'm fairly new to programming)

Tags: swift, class, struct, initialization

I am using the Swift Programming language. Here is the code:

```
class CalculatorBrain9iOS{

    ***bunch of code***
    ***bunch of code***

    private var accumulator = 0.0
    private var pending: PendingBinaryOperationInfo?

    private struct PendingBinaryOperationInfo {
        var binaryFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double
        var firstOperand: Double
    }

    func ...(...) {
        if let operation = ... {
            switch operation {
            case ...
            case RandomFunction.ThisCase(let function):
                pending = PendingBinaryOperationInfo(binaryFunction:
                function,
                firstOperand: accumulator)

            }
        }
    }
    ***bunch of code***
}
```

I want to change the private struct (PendingBinaryOperationInfo) to a class. It doesn't need inheritance so I figured I could just replace "private struct" with "class". But I keep getting initializer error messages on that line. Is it strictly because that new class is a nested class? Or are there other factors involved?

I guess my other big question here is: Aside from inheritance and value/reference, what other differences exist between classes and structs that makes it so that I can't just replace a struct with a class and still have the program run perfectly fine?

Comment: Did you have a reason for wanting to change this to a class, or are you just experimenting to get a feel for Swift?  Structs can do much of what a class can do including having methods defined on them.

Comment: Thats correct, I just want to get a feel for the differences in utilizing structs and classes in swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `struct` will automatically generate an initializer for you to initialize all properties.  A `class` will not synthesize a constructor for you unless you give initial values to all properties (or use Optionals which are automatically `nil`).  In your case, you need to write your own initializer:

```
class PendingBinaryOperationInfo {
    var binaryFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double
    var firstOperand: Double

    init(binaryFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double, firstOperand: Double) {
        self.binaryFunction = binaryFunction
        self.firstOperand = firstOperand
    }
}
```

---

You should be careful replacing a `struct` with a `class` for data.  It can lead to unexpected results since `class` is a *reference* type and `struct` is a *value* type.

Consider this example:

```
class Coord {
    var x = 0
    var y = 0
}

// Create an array with 5 Coords    
var coords = [Coord](count: 5, repeatedValue: Coord())

coords[0].x = 13
print(coords[1].x) // prints "13"
```

In this case, the array `coords` contains `5` references to the *same* `Coord` object.  So updating one updates them all.

If you change `class` to `struct`, then you will have `5` different values in the array and the result will print `0`.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thanks vacawama. My understanding of initializers is a little on the low side.

Comment: Quick follow-up question. Why must I use init, instead of of simply putting () at the end? Is it because the vars binaryFunction and firstOperand are considered arguments in this struct?

Comment: You can initialize a class or structure with just `()` at the end if all of the properties have default values, like I did for `Coord` above.  At the end of initialization, all properties must have a value which is why it requires you to set them in the initializer if they aren't given default values otherwise.  If I have answered your question, please click on the checkmark to the left of my answer to "accept" it.